# Python scatter plot vs line plot and column values

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, scatter

Wondering if anyone could clarify this for me.

Basically, I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
        Data_Value
Month_Day   
01-01     1.1
01-02     3.9
01-03     3.9
01-04     4.4
```

I can generate a line plot based on this dataframe using this code:

```
ax.plot(df.values)
```

I have had some problems generating a scatter plot from the same data frame and I am wondering if it's possible given that there is a "-" in the index column of the dataframe. However, I am also thinking that since it's possible to generate a line plot it should also be possible to do a scatter plot?

Any insights would be most welcome.

When I try this code:

```
df = df.reset_index()
df['Month_Day'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Month_Day'], format='%m-%d')
df.plot(type='scatter',x='Month_Day',y='Data_Value')
```

I get this error msg:

```
AttributeError: Unknown property type
```

My Pandas version: 0.19.2

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your issue totally, but if its just to create scatter plots, you can try to reset the index to convert 'Month_Date' to a regular column and also convert it to datetime. I tried the following:

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)

df['Month_Day'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Month_Day'], format='%m-%d')

# you can replace the year with any value, using 2020 as an example
df['Month_Day'] = [val.replace(year=2020) for val in df['Month_Day']]

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Month_Day  Data_Value
0 2020-01-01         1.1
1 2020-01-02         3.9
2 2020-01-03         3.9
3 2020-01-04         4.4
```

Then generate a scatter plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# generate the plot
plt.scatter(df['Month_Day'], df['Data_Value'])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks. However, I get the following error message:
TypeError: invalid type promotion

Also, I'm wondering, when I convert to datetime and the format is set to '%m-%d', shouldn't the year be automatically exluded?

Comment: Where are you getting that error. What is the version of pandas that you are using? Also for your second question - since there was no year mentioned in the original string, it defaults to 1900, hence I changed it to 2020 explicitly.

Comment: I'm using Jupyter and the Python version is 3.6.2.

I see, is it possible to omit the year completely?

Many thanks.

Comment: I was looking for the 'pandas' version. Anyways, to fix the error can you try adding these two lines to the code: from pandas.tseries import converter
converter.register()

Comment: Yes, it is possible to remove the year completely. I just shared it as an example as I was not sure based on the original post.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I still get the same error message (TypeError: invalid type promotion). Is it possible to exclude the year in the conversion to datetime? if so, how?

Comment: Can you update the question with your code? Also, can you check your pandas version: import pandas as pd
print(pd.__version__)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, but I believe you have to have `'Month_Day'` in the columns so you reset the index.

```
df = df.reset_index()
df.plot(kind='scatter',x='Month_Day',y='Data_Value')
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: @QuangHoang: that wasn't workiing for me. I get ValueError: scatter requires an x and y column.

Comment: @QuangHoang: thanks. I thought it would work with the index, too, but I guess not.

Comment: @mechanical_meat many thanks for your response. I tried your proposed solution, but I got this error message:
KeyError: 'Month_Day'

Comment: @user2629628: you would get that error if you didn't reset the index. Have you made sure to do that?

Comment: @mechanical_meat yes I have.